# How to Stop Single Tap From firing before Double Tap

Tags: gestures

I am trying to set a simple double tap recognition before moving to more complicated interactions.  I have the single and double tap being recognised. However, my problem is that the double tap doesn't fire without the single tap.

I have seen the code which covers introducing a requirement to fail, but the sample code I do not understand how to modify to make work with my standard approach.

Here is my code - at the moment I am just trying to get the log to fire and it is. But on double tap I get the single tap message which I don't want.  I have tried changing the TapGestureRecognizer event settings to no avail.

```
- (IBAction)didTapPhoto1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender; {


NSLog(@"Did Tap Photo1 !");

}



- (IBAction)didDoubleTapPhoto1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender; {


    NSLog(@"DoubleTap");
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UIGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` method.

`[singleTapGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapGestureRecognizer]`.

There is a side effect of this method, if you only tap one time on the screen, it will react slower than that without calling the method.

Edit: It seems that you create the gesture recognizer in Storyboard or xib. You can also do it with code.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapPhoto1:)] ;
singleGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 1 ;
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didDoubleTapPhoto1:)] ;
doubleGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 2 ;
// you can change self.view to any view in the hierarchy.
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleGR] ;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleGR] ;

[singleGR requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleGR] ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much - sorry to be a bit silly, but where exactly does this code go within my code above??  I get errors using "singletapgesturerecognizer" .  Should I replace that with didTapPhoto1?

Comment: No, place it after you add the two gestureRecognizers to a UIView. `singleTapGestureRecognizer` means the single tap gesture recognizer, `doubleTapGestureRecognizer` means double tap gesture recognizer.

Comment: Thanks - so within my header file?  I have two gesture recognisers, one with 1 tap in the event and one with two. I linked them both to the header file, so the header file has:                                                - (IBAction)didTapPhoto1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;   and the same for 'didDoubleTapPhoto1'.  I don't understand what you mean by "place it after you add the two gestureRecognizers to UIView."  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3882242 So you're using Storyboard to create the two gesture recognizer. You should get references to them use `New Referencing Outlet` in Connections inspector of UIGestureRecognizer, then call the method above in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @user3882242 You're welcome. Please accept the answer and up vote it if it helps. Have a good time in SO.